# The Server Commited a protocol Violation, section=ResponseStatusLine. With Httpgetresponse and Xpath

Tags: c#

I've got a piece of software I'm writing to control a local switch on my LAN network at let's say IP address 192.172.0.23:8000, whenever I try to download the `status.xml` from the switch or get a response I get the server committed a protocol violation section=responseStatusLine exception.

I have searched through these forums and tried the keepalive = false fix, I have

```
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing = "true"/>
    </settings>
  </system.net>
```

in the `App.Config` configuration section, but cannot seem to fix the issue, I know the addresses are valid as I can access them in Firefox, etc the two lines of code that are creating the issue are as follows:

```
     String URLString = @"http://" + sIP + @"/state.xml";
        try
        {
            //m_wClient.DownloadFile(URLString, @"C:\Sonardyne\test.xml"); // atempt to download file first to fix issue
            XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(URLString);
            XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
            XPathExpression expr = nav.Compile(@"/datavalues/relaystate");
            nav.Select(expr);
            switch (nav.Value)
            {
                case "0":
                    return false;
                case "1":
                    return true;
                default:
                    ConfigLoadedText.Text = "Failed to Load Satus from Controller IP:" + sIP;
                    return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            ConfigLoadedText.Text = e.Message + " IP:" + sIP;
            return false;
        }
```

And

```
            string sCommand = @"http://" + sIP + @"/state.xml?relayState=0"; // set the HTTP address to request to enable/disable the relay
            if (bRelayState)
            {
                sCommand = @"http://" + sIP + @"/state.xml?relayState=1";
            }
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sCommand);
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            //request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
            //request.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10; // set protocol version to try remove exception
            request.GetResponse();
```

Really stumped on this at the moment, and due to the whole Coronavirus situation unable to get any assistance from people in the office so any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my first post here so if I've done anything wrong please don't be too harsh.